# Getting the url after clicking a link with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, url, htmlunit

So this is my first question here after reading like hundreds of threads in this forum :D.
I want to click an HtmlAnchor with HtmlUnit and retrieve the underlying url.
Maybe I am using the wrong methods or something, but here is the code that I tried so far:

```
    public List<String> clickURLs(String searchAttribute) {
        try {
            wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false); wc.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); wc.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false); wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false); wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        HtmlPage page = wc.getPage(url);
        List<HtmlAnchor> links =page.getAnchors();
        for (HtmlAnchor link: links) {
            if(link.getTextContent().contains(searchAttribute)) {
                String href =link.click().getWebResponse().toString();
                System.out.println(href);
                list.add(href);
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        } // catch
        finally {
            wc.close();
        } // finally
        return list;
    } // clickURLs()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the expected output and what do you get instead?
If there is no redirect, you can also use the href from the anchor tag. But i'm not sure if i got your point.

Comment: The method is searching for links with a given String, the searchAttribute. Now I want it to click on every of those links and get the new URL, after the links were clicked. Currently I am getting no kind of output and I'm not sure why.

Comment: try System.out.println(link.asXML()); before clicking the link to make sure the links are found and the links really working using the href attribute. Maybe your links are using js to change the page...